# calling webmethod from javascript return string screws up newline characters

Tags: javascript, .net, xml

In javascript I call this method

```
//check for duplicate profiles on server side
PageMethods.CheckForDuplicates(FirstName, LastName, LinkedIn, email, function (result) { alert(result);}, function (result) { alert(result);});
```

The webservice method it calls is as follows

```
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string CheckForDuplicates(string sFirstName, string sLastName, string sLinkedIn, string sEmail)
    {
        string sError = "";           
            sError = "A possible duplicate profile was found with the following information\\n";
            sError += "Profile ID:" + pDuplicateProfile.ProfileID + "\\n";
            sError += "First Name:" + pDuplicateProfile.FirstName; if (string.Equals(pDuplicateProfile.FirstName.ToLower() + pDuplicateProfile.LastName.ToLower(), pTempProfileData.FirstName.ToLower() + pTempProfileData.LastName.ToLower())) { sError += "      <======NAME DUPLICATE===\\n"; } else { sError += "\\n"; }
            sError += "Last Name:" + pDuplicateProfile.LastName + "\\n";
            sError += "Work Email:" + pDuplicateProfile.BusinessEmail; if (pTempProfileData.BusinessEmail != "" && (pDuplicateProfile.BusinessEmail.ToLower().Contains(pTempProfileData.BusinessEmail.ToLower()) || pTempProfileData.BusinessEmail.ToLower().Contains(pDuplicateProfile.BusinessEmail.ToLower()))) { sError += "      <======BUSINESS EMAIL DUPLICATE===\\n"; } else { sError += "\\n"; }
            sError += "LinkedIn:" + pDuplicateProfile.LinkedIn; if (pTempProfileData.LinkedIn != "" && string.Equals(pDuplicateProfile.LinkedIn.ToLower(), pTempProfileData.LinkedIn.ToLower())) { sError += "      <======LINKED IN DUPLICATE===\\n"; } else { sError += "\\n"; }
            sError += "Please correct the problem and try again\\n";
            sError += "If you would like to continue to enter the information regardless (or make changes first)";          

        return sError;
    }
```

The issue is that all double backslash n's are printed, instead of actually doing a backslash n, when I call this via server side it does have new lines, therefore somehow (some XML thing or something) during the transfer from server to client side the carriage returns are ignored.

Comment: can u try Environment.NewLine?

Comment: you rock! that fixed it, dang can't believe I didn't look into that!

Comment: Enviroment.NewLine doesn't work everytime.